# server.listen callback not being called on error?

Tags: node.js, express

```
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('before');
    server.listen(port, err => {
      console.log('after');
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
      resolve();
    });
  });
```

Results:

```
before
[ ✘   error  ]  Application encountered an unexpected error, exiting
  2017-02-01T12:38:46.071Z   /home/karlm/dev/node/project/src/index.js:21:19
[ ✘   error  ]  { Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3030
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1045:20)
```

As you can see `before` is printed, but not `after`? It seems to be crashing and not calling the callback?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved in:

```
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    server.listen(port, () => {
      resolve();
    }).on('error', (err) => {
      reject(err);
    });
  });
```

The documentation didn't really hint that I had to use `on`.

Answer (score 1):

Can use like below,

```
server.listen(9000, 'localhost', function() {
    console.log('listening at http://%s:%s', 'localhost', 9000);
}).on('error', (e) => {
    console.error(e.message);
    throw e;
});
```